# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled error on iis 7/windows7/php 5.#/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, dll

i have windows 7 (32bit) running iis 7 with MongoDB and PHP 5.4 installed.   i'm having issues loading a the php extension.  based on other posts on the site, below is what i've tried doing.

1. got the dll "php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9.dll and copied it into the same directory as the php.ini file.  got the dll from this site "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads".   i should mention that i added the dll to any folder that contained the php.ini file, since i didn't know which .ini file was being used.
2. updated the php.ini file with "extension=php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9.dll". did this for all the php.ini files i found.
3. also updated the php.ini files with "extension=php_mongo.dll" cause i saw several posts on here and the web that mention this.

any input would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: You need to find a correct dll, which is exactly for your php and your OS. You have to add extension=dllName, so if your dll name is php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9.dll you do not need to add php_mongo.dll.

Comment: thanks for the reply salvador.  i'll research which dll i'll need.